# JDialog maximized state

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

my problem is related to JDialog. It must open in maximized state, and it has "maximize" buttons in both Ubuntu and Windows, but I can't find out any ways to tell application to be maximized. Here is the example:

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*

public class SampleDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EkmException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JButton button = new JButton("Sample");
                panel.add(button);
                dialog.add(panel);

                doMaximized(dialog);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void doMaximized(JDialog dialog) {
        //dialog.setExtendedState(...) - missing function

        //This will do good size, but without 'maximized' flag
        dialog.setSize(Toolkit.getDefatultToolkit().getSreenSize());
    }
}
```

So, for JDialog I can only have custom screen-fit-size, but "Maximize" button will be active, and that's messy. Are there any good ways to fix the problem?

Comment: A dialog in Windows don't have a maximise/restore buttons, it only has a close button.  I'm guessing that generally speaking this functionality is OS specific (if a dialog is "maximisable" or not)

Comment: Also, you are adding the dialog to a panel and the panel to a button? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Codebender No, my fault :) Fixed

Comment: @MadProgrammer It was tested in Windows XP, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I heard that minimize-maximize buttons in Windows don't exist for non-resizable dialogs, such as title icon ('cause we can resize form by clicking on the icon). Maybe that's really specific for these systems, there will be very sad...

Comment: @MadProgrammer For CentOS 5 there are no maximize/minimize buttons, so cross-platforming will not allow to do anything... Thank you for clarifying the situation.

Comment: For macOS, modal JDialog has maximize buttons.  and the dialog can be maximized, but not iconified (minimized).